# Which is faster: Passing an arithmetic parameter to a function, or calculating the arithmetic after calling the function?

Tags: java, performance, function

I have here two functions. They all have the same purposes, but they do not have the same parameter setup. Which one is faster? Thanks in advance.

```
//This function's purpose is to print x + y times.
//total = x + y
public void function(int total){
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++){
        System.out.println("Hello.");
    }
}

//This function is the same as the above.
//The value is calculated within a "for" loop
public void function(int x, int y){
    for (int i = 0; i < x + y; i++){
        System.out.println("Hello.");
    }
}

public void main(String[] arg){
    //Initial variables.
    int x = 4;
    int y = 6;

    //First function call
    function(x + y);

    //Second function call
    function(x, y);
}
```

Comment: You're preoptimizing. Use the version that makes sense from a logical and maintenance point of view. The execution time will likely be exactly the same. You just need to decide if the function should take one or two arguments, and if it's its responsibility to compute the sum or if it's the responsibility of the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually expect `javac` to optimize out the summation of `x + y` but it didn't. So this would leave things to other improvements on runtime like JIT or AOT.

Now thing is where would you use this Java code? On a desktop machine, server, Android mobile, Java card? If you don't have such concern then answer shouldn't be really important to you. However if you are targeting Java cards, then of course you should use the better one.

(Below is from javac / javap 1.7.0_09)

```
  public void function(int);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_2      
       2: iload_2       
       3: iload_1       
       4: if_icmpge     21
       7: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      10: ldc           #3                  // String Hello.
      12: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      15: iinc          2, 1
      18: goto          2
      21: return        

  public void function(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_3      
       2: iload_3       
       3: iload_1       
       4: iload_2       
       5: iadd          
       6: if_icmpge     23
       9: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      12: ldc           #3                  // String Hello.
      14: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      17: iinc          3, 1
      20: goto          2
      23: return
```

Answer (score 1):

One call to `System.out.println` is at least three orders of magnitude costlier than primitive add operations, so writing a function that prints something in a loop and worrying about int addition makes no sense. You could be approximating a sine function with Taylor series expansion up to the 100th member, and it would still be unlikely that you'd see a difference between the two versions of your function.

The main point is, even the most experienced Java veterans don't trust their instinct when it comes to performance. **Always** profile your code before even starting to think about bottlenecks.